# Is this expected behavior of react-router or a bug?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, single-page-application

I am using `react-router` v3. Transitioning to a route, say `/about`, and then clicking on a `<Link to="/about">` keeps on firing `onChange` on the root route, `/`, and the child route `/about` as well.

Is this the expected behavior? Since this route is not changing at all. And the browser back button behaves as expected as well.

Here is a small app on codesandbox which demonstrates this issue.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-onchange-3bi2p

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Route exact path="/" component={ComponentName}>
```

use exact befor your root route after that clicking on child route ,root route will not fire

Comment: I don't think v3 `<Link>` supports `exact`. It gives a warning `Warning: Received 'true' for a non-boolean attribute 'exact'`. There's a `onlyActiveOnIndex` and even that does not seem to make any difference.

Comment: `Link` does not have `exact`, I think he meant it as `Route`

Comment: ya sorry give exact to your route, and first of all, make route for all your child and for parent like <Route path='  ' component={component name } put all the routes into any component and give that component to render method, because i think  the way you use its routing way of angular not for  react i never see like this in react routing in any tutorial or video

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#route It's not there `Route` as well

Comment: @Tushar Till `react-router` v3 the JSX syntax was simply used to build the object form of route configuration. They should be identical. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#configuration-with-plain-routes